# Javascript Increment y=++x

Tags: javascript, variables, math, operators, increment

I am having a problem getting the following code to work.

```
<p><b>y=++x</b></p>

<button onclick="increPlusx_eg()">Show Result</button>

<p id="incrementPlusx_eg"></p>

<script>
function increPlusx_eg()
{
var x=25;
var y=++x;
var incpxEg=document.GetElementById("incrementPlusx_eg")
incpxEg.innerHTML="y+" + y + ", x=" + x;
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
JJ

Comment: `document.GetElementById` should be `document.getElementById`

Comment: Future reference, use your console, that would've shown the above error.

Comment: If it doesn't work how are we meant to know what it should do and thus how to get it to work? (which translates to always say what your error is, what you expect to happen, what is happening, etc.)

Comment: "document.GetElementById should be document.getElementById –  Igor Dymov"

 - This solved it. Thanks Igor, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You have `var x=25;` inside the function. Every time you run the function, you reset it.

Move the definition to outside the function.

```
var x=25;
function increPlusx_eg()
{
var y=++x;
```

You also have a function naming error. `GetElementById` starts with a *lower-case* `g`. You need to pay attention to your browser's JavaScript console where that sort of error will be reported.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, a simple solution would be to set this as HTML

```
<button id = "incrementPlusx_eg">Show Result</button>
```

and use the following JS

```
(function() {
    var x = 25;
    var y = ++x;
    var incpxEg = document.getElementById('incrementPlusx_eg');
    incpxEg.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('x: ' + x + '; y: ' + y);
    }, false);
})();
```